# TWS : job exiting without executing the script

Tags: tws

I am executing a job in TWS 
I am facing a problem where the job is exiting with status 0 without exexuting its script.

the script is getting executed scuccessfully when executed manually.

also , as seen in many posts on net , i tried to comparing the env variables in TWS and manually, but same 
problem , job is exiting without executing env command

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you question lacks crucial information like the os you are using, how you checked the "env" command...

TWS handles jobs on different systems (unix, windows, mainframe) differently depending on the system.

If you schedule your jobs on a unix system, you probably would like to check the .jobmanrc or the jobmanrc files to check how they load the user environment variables. See

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_8.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_8.5/awsrgmst41.htm%23dqx2custom515985
(on a windows system, it's the jobmanrc file I think).

Comment: If you feel the question is unclear, you can flag it as such.  Also, you should post the essential material from the link here and use the link as reference only.